# loop my function but not able to do it properly

Tags: javascript

i have a code which i want to run in loop but its only running one time i tried intervel but its not working

here is the code :

```
var getposition = 0;
var intervalinfo ;


         function setpostion(){
             document.getElementById("join").style.position = "absolute";
             document.getElementById("join").style.left = "0px";
             document.getElementById("join").style.top = "100px"

            intervalinfo = setInterval(getanimation ,50);
             }

             function getanimation() {
                 getposition += 5;
                document.getElementById("join").style.left = getposition + "px"; 

                 if (getposition > 500) {
                    // clearInterval(intervalinfo);
                     document.getElementById("join").style.left = "0px";

                     }

                 }

    window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(setpostion , 2000);

        }
```

Any help is really appreciable in advance :-)

Comment: It's because your setTimeout is after 2000 milliseconds .. Your setInterval is 50 milliseconds which has already passed in that 2000 so it doesn't

Comment: how to resolve it then ? i want to run it again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the `window.onload`.

Make sure your script is on the page below the 'join' element and just use

```
var getposition = 0;
var intervalinfo;


function setpostion() {
    document.getElementById("join").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("join").style.left = "0px";
    document.getElementById("join").style.top = "100px"

    intervalinfo = setInterval(getanimation, 50);
}

function getanimation() {
    getposition += 5;
    document.getElementById("join").style.left = getposition + "px";

    if (getposition > 500) {
        // clearInterval(intervalinfo);
        document.getElementById("join").style.left = "0px";

    }

}
setTimeout(setpostion, 2000);
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RobH/Nm8na/

Update (attempt 2):

If you want it to keep looping do this:

```
var getposition = 0;
var intervalinfo;


function setpostion() {
    document.getElementById("join").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("join").style.left = "0px";
    document.getElementById("join").style.top = "100px"

    intervalinfo = setInterval(getanimation, 50);
}

function getanimation() {
    getposition += 5;
    document.getElementById("join").style.left = getposition + "px";

    if (getposition > 500) {
        clearInterval(intervalinfo);
        document.getElementById("join").style.left = "0px";
        getposition = 0;
        setTimeout(setpostion, 2000);
    }

}
setTimeout(setpostion, 2000);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RobH/UqtAf/

Comment: i want to run it again once it done first time..

Comment: no its not working..once it cross 500 its coming to left position but not running again

Comment: @SachinRawal - yeah just noticed that - 1 sec.

Comment: @SachinRawal - it's correctly looping now, see update.

Comment: perfectttttttttttttttttt